# Toggling between $pristine and $dirty in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to detect when a user has entered values into any form field by using the $dirty property and setting a flag accordingly. Not surprisingly, this works:

```
$scope.$watch('formDetails.$dirty', function() {
  USR.userInputRecorded = true;
});
```

But I'd also like to detect when/if the user has emptied all fields and effectively restored the form to its original empty state. The snippet below does not work and I'm not sure why. Is there a way to watch for when the form changes back to "not dirty"?

```
$scope.$watch('formDetails.$pristine', function() {
  USR.userInputRecorded = false;
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.$watch('formDetails.$dirty', function(value) {
  if (value === '') {
    // field has been emptied;
    your.form.$setPristine(true);
  } else {
    USR.userInputRecorded = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. This seems to only detect the first time values are entered into any field. After this, the act of emptying all fields is not detected and reentering a value into any field does not produce a 'dirty' event again. Seems like it only works one time.